# IndentationError: unexpected indent in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting the following error
IndentationError: unexpected indent

def send_daily():
        '''Check reports to be sent daily'''

```
    current_day = calendar.day_name[now_datetime().weekday()]
    enabled_reports = frappe.get_all('Auto Email Report',
            filters={'enabled': 1, 'frequency': ('in', ('Daily', 'Weekdays', 'Weekly'))})

    for report in enabled_reports:
            auto_email_report = frappe.get_doc('Auto Email Report', report.name)

            # if not correct weekday, skip
            if auto_email_report.frequency == "Weekdays":
                    if current_day in ("Saturday", "Sunday"):
                            continue
            elif auto_email_report.frequency == 'Weekly':
                    schedule.every().monday.at('10:00')
                            continue
```

I am getting indentation error on line:
                    if current_day in ("Saturday", "Sunday"):
                            continue
How do i remove the indentation error?

Answer (score 0):

continue in elif is placed wrongly

```
elif auto_email_report.frequency == 'Weekly':
                schedule.every().monday.at('10:00')
                        continue
```

it should be:

```
elif auto_email_report.frequency == 'Weekly':
      schedule.every().monday.at('10:00')
      continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting error from: `if current_day in ("Saturday", "Sunday").`

Your error is in: `schedule.every().monday.at('10:00')`

***continue*** after error line should be:

```
elif auto_email_report.frequency == 'Weekly':
  schedule.every().monday.at('10:00')
  continue
```